# Add Social Login (FB/Google) to Cordova Typescript project

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, facebook-login, google-signin

I've tried to convert my angular app to cordova follows [this](https://medium.com/@nacojohn/convert-your-angular-project-to-mobile-app-using-cordova-f0384a7711a6) tutorial.
I done it but now i'm facing the problem to convert my social login (Facebook Login and Google) to cordova. Currently i'm using [angular-6-social-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-6-social-login) on web, but on cordova i can't get any dialog when i click "Sign In with" buttons. I get some errors in Console (when simulating iOS in browser):

```
The method FB.login can no longer be called from http pages. https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/06/08/enforce-https-facebook-login/
sdk.js?hash=3160dd80d8bcaa25ffc3fc1ccc6adb00:259
ERROR
```

And in IOS:
[facebook error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBUf9.png)

because of `http://localhost`.
For google login i get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/on7SN.png).
My question is: Is there any way to fix it? 
Cordova plugins is in JS([cordova-plugin-googleplus](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus)) and i can't see docs for Typescript.
Should i use cordova plugins (JS) or angular-6-social-login ?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some plugins for this in cordova with types folder. 
[This is for Facebook](https://github.com/jimijings11/cordova-plugin-facebook4) and [this is for google](https://github.com/jimijings11/cordova-plugin-googleLogin).
Enjoy.